# Sum $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {n2^n\over(n+2)!} $?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, factorial, telescopic-series

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {n2^n\over(n+2)!}
$$
The exercise mentions that this can be written as a telescopic series;
I've been trying to write it in such a way but I'm stuck, can't seem to find one! Any help is much appreciated!

---

Solution:

So n*2^n can be written as (n+2)*2^n-2^(n+1); from there the partial sum is reduced to 1 - 2^(k+1)/(k+2)! and the sum is 1.

Comment: Finding a telescopic series representation is not the Universal Remedy. Unless, you are said by the author of the question to look for such a representation, **very very few series** can be "summed" using such a representation.

Comment: Besides, next time, show your work...

Comment: give the details of what book, what page what exercise this is from

Comment: It's an exercise proposed by my teacher in a set of exercises on telescopic series; I'm revising for finals and I didn't have this one solved - I honestly have no idea how to re-write it; I only thought about writing 2^n as the sum of binomial coefficients - but still, no idea how to play around that!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $e^{x} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$.
Hence
$$ e^{x} - 1 - \frac{x}{1!} - \frac{x^{2}}{2!} = \sum_{n = 3}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}. $$

$$ \frac{e^{x} - 1 - \frac{x}{1!} - \frac{x^{2}}{2!}}{x^{2}} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{(n+2)!}. $$
Now take the derivative with respect to $x$ on both sides, then multiply both sides by $x$ and plug in $2$ for $x$.

Comment: This one has a little bit of a complicated derivative. Even though OP didn't show their work, this is much more easily done with telescoping series.